# Pass this to recurive jquery animate function

Tags: javascript, jquery, animation, recursion

I'm trying to make an infinite animation loop. A div needs to make a rhombus shape movement all the time. but it needs to animate "this".

I have already tried a few options that usually save me in a scenario like this, but I can't get it to work. I'll post my current tryout and some older ones below:

TypeError: self is undefined

```
var shakeCounter = 0;
    function loopShake(self) {
        if (shakeCounter % 4 === 0)
            self.animate({left: '+=' + settings.shakeX, top: '+=' + settings.shakeX}, settings.shakeSpeed, 'linear', function(){ loopShake(self); });
        else if (shakeCounter % 4 === 1)
            self.animate({left: '-=' + settings.shakeX, top: '+=' + settings.shakeX}, settings.shakeSpeed, 'linear', function(){ loopShake(self); });
        else if (shakeCounter % 4 === 2)
            self.animate({left: '-=' + settings.shakeX, top: '-=' + settings.shakeX}, settings.shakeSpeed, 'linear', function(){ loopShake(self); });
        else
            self.animate({left: '+=' + settings.shakeX, top: '-=' + settings.shakeX}, settings.shakeSpeed, 'linear', function(){ loopShake(self); });
        shakeCounter++;
    }(this);
    loopShake();
```

Below works, but an animation in an interval always gives unexpected results (for me)

```
    var myTimer;
    if (settings.shake) {
        myTimer = setInterval(
                (function(self) {
                    var shakeCounter = 0;
                    return function() {
                        if (shakeCounter % 4 === 0)
                            self.animate({left: '+=' + settings.shakeX, top: '+=' + settings.shakeX}, settings.shakeSpeed);
                        else if (shakeCounter % 4 === 1)
                            self.animate({left: '-=' + settings.shakeX, top: '+=' + settings.shakeX}, settings.shakeSpeed);
                        else if (shakeCounter % 4 === 2)
                            self.animate({left: '-=' + settings.shakeX, top: '-=' + settings.shakeX}, settings.shakeSpeed);
                        else
                            self.animate({left: '+=' + settings.shakeX, top: '-=' + settings.shakeX}, settings.shakeSpeed);
                        shakeCounter++;
                    }
                })(this), 0);
    }
```

Furthermore I tried the obvious things like `function loopShake(this)` or `var myElement = this; function loopShake(myElement)`, but that also got me nowhere.

Hope you guys can help me!

Comment: I think you can remove `loopShake();` from the first block which you have placed right after the function definition. This is probably the reason why you are getting the error because you didn't send `this` to it?!

Comment: Man, I have been working on this way too long :D I couldnt remove it because that is what called the function in the first place, but changing it to loopShake(this) fixed everything! Thanks, your comment pointed me in the right direction!